# Unity game 2D sidescroller health bar C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding and I have been making a 2D sidescroller game in Unity using C#. I am trying to add a health bar made of 5 hearts, half a heart = 10% of health (picture of health bar is attached). [image]
 . [image]

I have looked online for hours trying to figure out how to code this type of health bar into my game, but I could not find anything. Do I make a GUItexture first? what will the code look like? I want it so every time the player takes 10 points of damage the health bar loses half a heart. What should I add to my already existing scripts and will I have to make a new script?

Anyway will be appreciated thank you.

Here is my player code...

```
      using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Handle hitpoints and damages
/// </summary>
public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Total hitpoints
    /// </summary>
    public int hp = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enemy or player?
    /// </summary>
    public bool isEnemy = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Inflicts damage and check if the object should be destroyed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="damageCount"></param>
    public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // 'Splosion!
            SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);

            // Dead!
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
    {
        // Is this a shot?
        ShotScript shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
        if (shot != null)
        {
            // Avoid friendly fire
            if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy)
            {
                Damage(shot.damage);

                // Destroy the shot
                Destroy(shot.gameObject); // Remember to always target the game object, otherwise you will just remove the script
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my healthscript

```
 using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Handle hitpoints and damages
/// </summary>
public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Total hitpoints
    /// </summary>
    public int hp = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enemy or player?
    /// </summary>
    public bool isEnemy = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Inflicts damage and check if the object should be destroyed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="damageCount"></param>
    public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // 'Splosion!
            SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);

            // Dead!
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
    {
        // Is this a shot?
        ShotScript shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
        if (shot != null)
        {
            // Avoid friendly fire
            if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy)
            {
                Damage(shot.damage);

                // Destroy the shot
                Destroy(shot.gameObject); // Remember to always target the game object, otherwise you will just remove the script
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would probably use a quad(mesh) i create in a script like here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html

with a Transparent Shader like

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/shader-TransCutDiffuse.html

and edit the rightmost vertices to where you want them when you loose health. So if your mesh is 10 units long for 5 Hearts then 4.5 Hearts would be 9 units long instead. An example of editing vertex data is example 2 or 3 in this:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

The only thing left then is to position it right

Comment: how would I connect this code to the player and health scripts?

Comment: mmh i can onyl see your healthscript twice now. The way you would do it is create the mesh in the Start() method of the script which has access to the health data. And then everytime the health changes  you call a method updateHealthGUI() or something which takes care of the changes to the vertices depending on the current state of the health.

Comment: also creating procedural meshes can seem a bit overwhelming at first, just try to create a quad in a start method and play around a bit untill you feel comfortable. There also exists an official package of unity Example Projects for procedural meshes which is quite helpful. edit: http://u3d.as/content/unity-technologies/procedural-examples/3zu